# Is "delivered price" in this sentence same as "final price"?

Tags: meaning

Would "delivered prices" mean "final prices" that people would end up paying?
sequestration here refers to sequestration of CO2 in the atmosphere.

But because sequestration does not affect the cost of electricity transmission and distribution, **delivered prices** will rise less, by no more than 50 percent.

Thank you

Comment: Would you please provide some more of the context where this sentence occurs? That will help us figure out how to make sense of "delivered prices".

Answer (score 2):

The delivered price is the final price including transportation costs.

The [definition of "delivered price" from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delivered%20price) is *a price for which a seller agrees to deliver merchandise to a purchaser at a designated place and which usually includes the f.o.b. price at the shipping point plus lawful transportation charges actually incurred in delivery*

Another few definitions:

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/delivered-price)
**Delivered price** is *a price for goods which includes the cost of packing, transport, etc.*

From [Financial Dictionary](https://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/delivered+pricing)
**Delivered pricing** is *the charging of a PRICE for a product that includes the cost of transporting the product from the manufacturer to the customer.*

From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/delivered-price)
**Delivered price** is *a quoted price of merchandise, as steel, that includes freight charges from the basing point to the point of delivery, usually f.o.b.*

From [Marketing Dictionary of Monash Business School](https://www.monash.edu/business/marketing/marketing-dictionary/d/delivered-pricing#:%7E:text=a%20pricing%20method%20in%20which,cost%20to%20the%20quoted%20price.)
**Delivered pricing** is *a pricing method in which the final price to the buyer is adjusted to include transportation costs; the seller takes responsibility for arranging delivery but adds the cost to the quoted price.*

The meaning of the phrase is that the transmission (transportation) price of the electricity will not be affected, thus the final price including transportation - delivered price - will rise not so much.

Comment: Note f.o.b means free on board